# element 'topic' attribute 'is synchronous' the attribute 'is synchronous' is not allowed

Tags: magento2

Good Morning,

Here is my problem and the screenshot link below is self-explanatory:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gOoTAzLBuvEjx5pmFFWZUEj-t7oa4icd/view 
Can someone help me fix that issue?
Best regards,
Pascal

Answer (score 0):

**Most likely in layout XMLs you have declarations like**

```
<block type="..."
```

**Which does not correspond to lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/elements.xsd and need to be replaced to**

```
<block class="..."
```

Answer (score 0):

removed attribute **is_synchronous** from the ***communication.xml*** and the website worked again. also cleared cache .